# dataTable plugin css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my code   css  is not  working..

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/js/dataTables.tableTools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Above all  are js files.

```
<link src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css">
<link src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

These  are the links that i used for CSS.
Export  to xls/pdf  also  not working properly.Jquery code is given  below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "print",
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }
            ]
        },
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    });
```

First time  i am using dataTable.js .Please do help to correct my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not found any css named files in your html? You have included only the js files. Include the `.css` files in your head tag

Comment: it seems that youyour js address is incorrect. they are `//cdn` change them to `http://cdn`

Comment: I  added  http://.,but still not working

Comment: Show the error in console

Comment: Sorry! It  was  my mistake..I  corrected by replacing src  with  href in <link> tag

Answer (score 0):

in your css link 
second one link not working 
just remove // in src="//cdn"
 try this one

```
<link src="http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: // is normal to have in a CSS link, it just means it will automatically detect http or https.

Comment: https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/css/dataTables.tableTools.css